# How do you format the body of a JMS text message?

Tags: java, jms

Does everyone just use XML in the message? Are there any good alternatives to XML?  If you do use XML, do you define an XML Schema so clients know how to send messages to your service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use XML, but I think the important thing is to tailor the solution to the problem.  The reason we use XML is that we are basically sending an object across in the message.  There's no reason it can't be plain text, if applicable for the message you are sending, using headers to send along properties if appropriate.

---

We haven't defined an XSD or DTD for our XML messages, but we do have a formal document describing their composition so that other teams can use our feeds without bugging us.

Answer (score 1):

XML, CSV, HTML, a simple word or sentence, ...  Any of these are valid depending on the context in which the message is used and created.  Just keep it simple and send what is needed in that context.

It is very flexible and can be adapted to the problem space.

Answer (score 1):

XML is probably the most popular along with JSON a close second - but as others have said in this thread - XML, CSV, JSON or even HTML are fine.

XSDs are overrated really - their only real value is if you want your clients/customers to code generate marshalling code (e.g. using JAXB) or if you want to let folks use XSDs in their editors / IDE to get smart completion

Comment: I like XSDs for use in IDEs - for both smart completion and validation.